# Change value of each property in array of objects in javascript - map() method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this array of objects:

```
var firstArray = [{created:"01/01/2015 03:24:33 AM", lat:"123"}, {created:"01/02/2015 03:24:33 AM", lat:"123"}];
```

I want a new array of objects with the datetimes converted to milliseconds:

```
var newArray = [{created:1420070400000, lat:"123"}, {created:1420156800000, lat:"123"}];
```

How do I change the values of the first property in each object? I'm trying .map(), but maybe that isn't right. What am I missing? I've tried a bunch of things, but just wrote it in quotes in the code below to try and convey what I'm after. Thanks.

```
var newArray = firstArray.map( "the value of the first property in each object" (Date.parse());
```

Comment: Do you want to mutate the objects or create new ones?

Comment: I want new ones. The answer below did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The argument to `.map` should be a function where you make your appropriate changes.

```
newArray = firstArray.map(function (item) {
    return {
        created: Date.parse(item.created),
        lat: item.lat
    };
});
```

Comment: Rather "build the new value" instead of "make changes" :-)

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I'd like to have the flexibility of both the firstArray and the newArray. Thanks!